# Mocha not fail test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a simple test that should be failed but it passed with an error.

My code:

```
    it('my test', async () => {
        const result = await resolvingPromise;

        expect(result).to.equal('ok');

        async function analyzeData() {

            let getData = db.getData(1);

            let data = await getData;

            expect(data.field).to.equal(null);
        }

        analyzeData();
    });
```

In this test first expect is ok but the expect inside the async function must fail but test returns me that is passed but I have seen this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected Fri, 02 Mar 2018 09:47:06 GMT to equal null
(node:295) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

how can I handle a rejectin this way?
or I need to change my async functuion here in test?
What is the good approach so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocha will wait for any promise to resolve that is returned from the test before moving onto the next test.

With the current code, `undefined` is being returned from the test function immediately, which means mocha moves on without waiting for the `analyzeData` promise to resolve. This results in a successful test, then at a later point an unhandled rejection, rather than waiting and a test failure.

```
it('my test', async function(){
  const result = await resolvingPromise;
  expect(result).to.equal('ok');
})

it('next test', async function(){
  let data = await db.getData(1);  
  expect(data.field).to.equal(null);
})
```

Comment: Also that's an odd structure for a test, but I assume you are just working out promises.

Comment: it returns the same problem sorry, field is not null and MUST be fail the test, but pass...

Comment: You still get an unhandled rejection?

Comment: yes UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Comment: Do you still get an unhandled rejection with each promise split into it's own test?

Comment: If I split into two tests it works fine because second fail as I want. But I need to check It in the same test :(

Comment: Oh.. try `await analyzeData()` instead of `return analyzeData()`, I think I'm thinking in A+ promises rather than async/await.

Comment: Ok It works, return inside async and await analyzeData() after the expects works fine! It doesn't work inside the async functiomn